# Migrating ArcSDE data to Oracle Spatial?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, migration, spatial-etl

We've got all the geospatial information of our company within an ArcSDE Database (over oracle  Server):

- points
- lines
- polygons

We consume these data with ArcGIS Desktop and with ArcGIS Server.

We are planning to migrate all the information to Oracle Spatial.

Is using Spatial ETL a way to do that ?

Comment: Questions with "best" in them tend to get closed as being opionion-based. Please **edit** the question to contain critical details -- version of Oracle (before and after), version of ArcGIS  (before and after), OS platform (before and after), the current geometry storage (SDEBINARY, SDELOB, ST_GEOMETRY), and whether any of the tables are involved in complex geodatabase capabilities (topology, parcel fabric, domains,...)

Comment: Two more points to clarify: are you moving the data to a new Oracle database ? Or do you want to keep the data in the same database and migrate in-place ? And also: do you intend to keep on using ArcGIS to access the data once it is in Oracle Spatial ?

Comment: I want to keep the data in the same database .

Comment: The current data type is SDE.ST_GEOMETRY i want to move iit to SDO_GEOMETRY